# android gallery like photo gallery in mobile

Tags: android, gallery

i need android photo gallery(same as mobile) like below image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot is from open source app Gallery 3D, which is released on [Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.coolandroidappzfree.media&feature=search_result). You can download source code [here](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Gallery3D).